# Prove that an open ball is a closed set in ultrametric space

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

[image]

---

Take $B_r(x)$. Consider $y \notin B_r(x)$. Then $d(y,x)\geq r$. Take $B_r(y)$, then consider a point $z \in B_r(y)$. We'll note $d(y,z)<r$.

Assume that $z \in B_r(x)$, then $d(z,x)<r$.

So we have:

1. $d(y,z)<r$
2. $d(z,x)<r$

Then $d(y,x) \leq \max\{d(y,z), d(z,x)\}$ implies $d(y,x)<r$, which contradicts earlier established $d(y,x)\geq r$. Hence $z \notin B_r(x), z \in S-B_r(x)$, i.e.  $B_r(y) \subseteq S-B_r(x)$, hence $S-B_r(x)$ is open and hence $B_r(x)$ is a closed set $\square$.

Am I correct?

Comment: I think your answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks for input.

Comment: Yes. Correct. Because $y\in \overline {B_r(x)}  \setminus  B_r(x)$  then $\rho (y,x)=r$ in any metric space... BTW some authors write $B(x,r)$  or $B_{\rho}(x,r)$  for $B_r(x) $.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B(x,r)$ be an open ball and suppose $z \in \overline{B(x,r)}$. In particular: $B(z,r)$ intersects $B(x,r)$, say $y \in B(x,r) \cap B(z,r)$. Then $d(x,y) < r$ and $d(y,z) < r$ and so:

$$d(z,x) \le \max(d(z,y), d(y,x)) < r$$

or $z \in B(x,r)$ and so $B(x,r)$ is closed, as it already contains every point of its closure.

Another fun fact: $B(x,r) = B(y,r)$ for every point $y \in B(x,r)$, which I remember as "every point of an ultrametric ball is its centre". The proof is similar to the above one.